# Why the spectrum of square lattice with $\Phi=m \Phi_0$ with $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ is the same as $\Phi=0$?

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, gauss-law, gauge-invariance, lattice-gauge-theory

In solid-state physics, in the study of square lattice in a perpendicular homogenous magnetic field, I have seen that when the flux per cell is an integer multiple of the flux quantum, i.e. $\Phi=m \Phi_0$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}$, then the spectrum of the lattice is equivalent to the case that there is no magnetic field (i.e. $\Phi=0$); otherwise, when $m$ is a rational number (non-integer), the spectrum is the Hofstadter butterfly.

**Question.** Why does this equivalence for integer values of $m$ happen? or, in other words, what is responsible for this equivalence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hamiltonian with flux $\Phi=m\Phi_0$ is always gauge-equivalent to one with $\Phi=0$. In other words there is a unitary transformation $U$ such that
$UH(m\Phi_0)U^{-1}=H(0)$. $U$ is of the form $U=e^{i\sum_{\mathbf{r}}\theta_{\mathbf{r}} n_{\mathbf{r}}}$, where $n_\mathbf{r}$ is the charge operator on site $\mathbf{r}$, and $\theta_{\mathbf{r}}$ is some parameter.

An equivalent statement is that the gauge field is compact U(1), so $\Phi$ is defined mod $\Phi_0$. The precise meaning is the previous paragraph.

Comment: Thanks; I would be obliged if you kindly help me with my consequent questions:                               $\qquad\quad 1$. By "is always gauge-equivalent ", do you mean that the claim is valid in general for any other lattice in a magnetic field? even for loop chains?                                         $\qquad 2$. . May I ask you to kindly explain more why there exists such a gauge-equivalence for integer $m$ only? why it is not valid for other $m$? I apologize, my major is not Physics and it is a bit complicated for me to understand it.

Comment: @sara96 1. For other lattices, one has to be a little more careful because there could be multiple inequivalent "cells". Basically, one has to count flux through each closed paths on the lattice and if they are all integer multiples of $\Phi_0$, then it is gauge-equivalent to 0 flux everywhere.

Comment: @sara96 2. The gauge transformation does not change flux (mod $\Phi_0$). So if $m$ is not an integer, it is physically different from 0 flux. You might be interested in my answer to a related question, where some details are spelled out: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/773537/large-gauge-transformation-in-mathrmu1-flux-threading-argument/773597

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and attention; I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. May I ask you to introduce a reference (if there is any) that speaks about this topic so that I can learn more?

Comment: @sara96 You might want to check Bernevig and Hughes's textbook "topological insulators and topological superconductors". I think they have a pretty thorough discussion about the problem of square lattice in a uniform magnetic field.